# Change iframe src without refreshing parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I have a page within an ASP.NET site. The iframe is inside an Ajax Update Panel.

I have a need to change the src attribute of the iframe from javascript which I can do. The problem is that when the src attribute changes, the parent page refreshes.

I need to only have the frame navigate, not the parent page.

HTML:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <iframe id="previewIframe" runat="server" Width="800px"></iframe> 
            </ContentTemplate>               
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

javascript:

```
var frame = $("#previewIframe");
frame.setAttribute('src', "http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Is the frame actually called previewIframe when its actually generated? or is ASP.NET doing its prepending of the control name to it?

Comment: Also in jQuery it should be : $("#previewIframe").attr('src', "http://www.google.com"), setAttribute is for the javascript DOM.

Comment: I threw on the ClientIDMode="Static" for the iframe and refreshed

<iframe id="previewIframe" Width="800px"></iframe>

Comment: ahh, that did it. combining the static ID and updating jquery works now.

markup:

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <iframe ClientIDMode="Static" id="previewIframe" src="" runat="server" Width="800px"></iframe> 
                </ContentTemplate>               
            </asp:UpdatePanel>  

javascript:

    $("#previewIframe").attr('src', "http://www.google.com");

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <iframe ClientIDMode="Static" id="previewIframe" src="" runat="server"></iframe> 
            </ContentTemplate>               
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

javascript:

```
$("#previewIframe").attr('src', "http://www.google.com");
```

forgot that in ASP the element ID's are not sacred, they are prepended eg. "MainContent_previewIframe"

once I added the ClientIDMode="Static" attribute jquery could properly reference the element.

Also updating the jquery method to $("#previewIframe").attr('src','google.com'); - I was mixing straight javascript and jquery. I should know by now to stick to one.